# Beautifulsoup not work right

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to parse from http://thuvienphapluat.vn/ and i want to snip div tag with id="VBPLMOI".

When  I type it in console by css $$('#VBPLMOI')[0], I get the result which is array with 5 elements in div tag, it right with this page.
[pic of 5 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gie2.jpg)

```html
<div id="VBPLMOI" style="display: block;">
                        


        <div class="content-0">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    1</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="342641">
                        <a onclick="Doc_CT(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-06-2017-TT-BGDDT-Quy-che-dao-tao-vua-lam-vua-hoc-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342641.aspx">Thông tư 06/2017/TT-BGDĐT Quy chế đào tạo vừa làm vừa học trình độ đại học do Bộ trưởng Bộ Giáo dục và Đào tạo ban hành</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="links-bot">
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,1)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Tiếng Anh</a>
                        |
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,2)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Văn bản gốc</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_Rel(MemberGA)" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,4)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-06-2017-TT-BGDDT-Quy-che-dao-tao-vua-lam-vua-hoc-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342641.aspx?tab=3">Lược đồ</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_ST(MemberGA)" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,3)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-06-2017-TT-BGDDT-Quy-che-dao-tao-vua-lam-vua-hoc-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342641.aspx?tab=4">Liên quan hiệu lực</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_DL(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-06-2017-TT-BGDDT-Quy-che-dao-tao-vua-lam-vua-hoc-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342641.aspx?tab=7">Tải về</a>
                        
                        
                    </p>
                    
                </div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Ban hành:</span>
                    15/03/2017</p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Hiệu lực:</span> <span style="color:#8C0945"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Tình trạng:</span> <span class="text-red"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Cập nhật:
                        16/03/2017</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="content-1">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    2</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="342642">
                        <a onclick="Doc_CT(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-07-2017-TT-BGDDT-lien-ket-dao-tao-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342642.aspx">Thông tư 07/2017/TT-BGDĐT Quy định về liên kết đào tạo trình độ đại học do Bộ trưởng Bộ Giáo dục và Đào tạo ban hành</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="links-bot">
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,1)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Tiếng Anh</a>
                        |
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,2)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Văn bản gốc</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_Rel(MemberGA)" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,4)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-07-2017-TT-BGDDT-lien-ket-dao-tao-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342642.aspx?tab=3">Lược đồ</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_ST(MemberGA)" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,3)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-07-2017-TT-BGDDT-lien-ket-dao-tao-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342642.aspx?tab=4">Liên quan hiệu lực</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_DL(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-07-2017-TT-BGDDT-lien-ket-dao-tao-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342642.aspx?tab=7">Tải về</a>
                        
                        
                    </p>
                    
                </div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Ban hành:</span>
                    15/03/2017</p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Hiệu lực:</span> <span style="color:#8C0945"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Tình trạng:</span> <span class="text-red"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Cập nhật:
                        16/03/2017</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="content-0">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    3</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="342711">
                        <a onclick="Doc_CT(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Van-hoa-Xa-hoi/Quyet-dinh-329-QD-TTg-De-an-phat-trien-van-hoa-doc-trong-cong-dong-den-2020-dinh-huong-2030-2017-342711.aspx">Quyết định 329/QĐ-TTg năm 2017 phê duyệt Đề án phát triển văn hóa đọc trong cộng đồng đến năm 2020, định hướng đến năm 2030 do Thủ tướng Chính phủ ban hành</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="links-bot">
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,1)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Tiếng Anh</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_Scan(MemberGA)" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,2)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Van-hoa-Xa-hoi/Quyet-dinh-329-QD-TTg-De-an-phat-trien-van-hoa-doc-trong-cong-dong-den-2020-dinh-huong-2030-2017-342711.aspx?tab=2">Văn bản gốc</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_Rel(MemberGA)" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,4)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Van-hoa-Xa-hoi/Quyet-dinh-329-QD-TTg-De-an-phat-trien-van-hoa-doc-trong-cong-dong-den-2020-dinh-huong-2030-2017-342711.aspx?tab=3">Lược đồ</a>
                        |
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,3)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Liên quan hiệu lực</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_DL(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Van-hoa-Xa-hoi/Quyet-dinh-329-QD-TTg-De-an-phat-trien-van-hoa-doc-trong-cong-dong-den-2020-dinh-huong-2030-2017-342711.aspx?tab=7">Tải về</a>
                        
                        
                    </p>
                    
                </div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Ban hành:</span>
                    15/03/2017</p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Hiệu lực:</span> <span style="color:#8C0945"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Tình trạng:</span> <span class="text-red"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Cập nhật:
                        16/03/2017</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="content-1">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    4</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="321445">
                        <a onclick="Doc_CT(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Tai-chinh-nha-nuoc/Nghi-dinh-25-2017-ND-CP-bao-cao-tai-chinh-nha-nuoc-321445.aspx">Nghị định 25/2017/NĐ-CP về báo cáo tài chính nhà nước</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="links-bot">
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,1)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Tiếng Anh</a>
                        |
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,2)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Văn bản gốc</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_Rel(MemberGA)" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,4)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Tai-chinh-nha-nuoc/Nghi-dinh-25-2017-ND-CP-bao-cao-tai-chinh-nha-nuoc-321445.aspx?tab=3">Lược đồ</a>
                        |
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,3)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Liên quan hiệu lực</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_DL(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Tai-chinh-nha-nuoc/Nghi-dinh-25-2017-ND-CP-bao-cao-tai-chinh-nha-nuoc-321445.aspx?tab=7">Tải về</a>
                        
                        
                    </p>
                    
                </div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Ban hành:</span>
                    14/03/2017</p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Hiệu lực:</span> <span style="color:#8C0945"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Tình trạng:</span> <span class="text-red"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Cập nhật:
                        15/03/2017</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="content-0">
            <div class="left-col">
                <div class="number">
                    5</div>
                <div class="nq">
                    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="342492">
                        <a onclick="Doc_CT(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Thuong-mai/Chi-thi-02-CT-BCT-tang-cuong-quan-ly-an-toan-thuc-pham-doi-voi-san-xuat-kinh-doanh-ruou-2017-342492.aspx">Chỉ thị 02/CT-BCT năm 2017 về tăng cường quản lý an toàn thực phẩm đối với sản xuất, kinh doanh rượu do Bộ Công thương ban hành</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="links-bot">
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,1)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Tiếng Anh</a>
                        |
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,2)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Văn bản gốc</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_Rel(MemberGA)" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,4)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Thuong-mai/Chi-thi-02-CT-BCT-tang-cuong-quan-ly-an-toan-thuc-pham-doi-voi-san-xuat-kinh-doanh-ruou-2017-342492.aspx?tab=3">Lược đồ</a>
                        |
                        <a onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,3)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" style="color:#AFAFAF;">Liên quan hiệu lực</a>
                        |
                        <a onclick="Doc_DL(MemberGA)" href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Thuong-mai/Chi-thi-02-CT-BCT-tang-cuong-quan-ly-an-toan-thuc-pham-doi-voi-san-xuat-kinh-doanh-ruou-2017-342492.aspx?tab=7">Tải về</a>
                        
                        
                    </p>
                    
                </div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Ban hành:</span>
                    14/03/2017</p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Hiệu lực:</span> <span style="color:#8C0945"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p><span style="color:#000">Tình trạng:</span> <span class="text-red"><span id="span_a" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,0)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip()">Đã biết</span></span></p>
                <p>
                    <span style="color: #000">Cập nhật:
                        15/03/2017</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    

                        <p>
                            <a class="details" href="/van-ban-moi">Xem tiếp »</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

But when I use the beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bsa
import requests
url="http://thuvienphapluat.vn"
page_text=requests.get(url).text
soup =Bsa(page_text,"html.parser")
print soup.prettify()

vbpl=soup.select('#VBPLMOI')
for itext in vbpl:
    print itext.prettify()
```

It just give out first result.

```html
<div id="VBPLMOI">
 <div class="content-0">
  <div class="left-col">
   <div class="number">
    1
   </div>
   <div class="nq">
    <p class="nqTitle" lawid="342641">
     <a href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-06-2017-TT-BGDDT-Quy-che-dao-tao-vua-lam-vua-hoc-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342641.aspx" onclick="Doc_CT(MemberGA)">
      Thông tư 06/2017/TT-BGDĐT Quy chế đào tạo vừa làm vừa học trình độ đại học do Bộ trưởng Bộ Giáo dục và Đào tạo ban hành
     </a>
    </p>
    <p class="links-bot">
     <a onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,1)" style="color:#AFAFAF;">
      Tiếng Anh
     </a>
     |
     <a onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,2)" style="color:#AFAFAF;">
      Văn bản gốc
     </a>
     |
     <a href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-06-2017-TT-BGDDT-Quy-che-dao-tao-vua-lam-vua-hoc-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342641.aspx?tab=3" onclick="Doc_Rel(MemberGA)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,4)">
      Lược đồ
     </a>
     |
     <a href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-06-2017-TT-BGDDT-Quy-che-dao-tao-vua-lam-vua-hoc-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342641.aspx?tab=4" onclick="Doc_ST(MemberGA)" onmouseout="hideddrivetip();" onmouseover="LS_Tip_New(13,0,3)">
      Liên quan hiệu lực
     </a>
     |
     <a href="http://thuvienphapluat.vn/van-ban/Giao-duc/Thong-tu-06-2017-TT-BGDDT-Quy-che-dao-tao-vua-lam-vua-hoc-trinh-do-dai-hoc-342641.aspx?tab=7" onclick="Doc_DL(MemberGA)">
      Tải về
     </a>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please help me to get all results.

Thanks & Best regards.

Comment: ids are supposed to be unique, but you can try `.select('[id=VBPLMOI]')` or `.find_all(id='VBPLMOI')`.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? According to [BS doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), those parsers behave differently on different Python version.

Comment: I tried as what you said and I get only one div element in console.
https://ibb.co/mAGaYv

Comment: @saurabhbaid Sorry I missing a little, I updated $$('#VBPLMOI')[0]. It contains 5 div tag

Comment: @saurabhbaid: https://ibb.co/cgovka

Comment: @Ryan: Not working, like my result

Comment: The problem is with the parser, I would suggest you to use 'html5lib' parser

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do how the object returned by requests is parsed by beautifulsoup. If you look at the output from `print soup.prettify()` it looks like the div with id='VBPLMOI' closes after the first result. When I tried using selenium webdriver to retrieve the page, I am able to get all 5 divs.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
url="http://thuvienphapluat.vn"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
vbpl=soup.select('#VBPLMOI')
driver.quit()
for itext in vbpl:
    print itext.prettify()
```

Comment: I get the erro: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH."

Comment: Why do you need to use webdriver? request moduve is sufficient to get the source.

Comment: To use the Firefox webdriver, the geckodriver has to be installed, and the path to its .exe added. This is a recent change to bs4.

Comment: I find out an interesting thing, when I save page of this url first, and open this  local html, my select is right. Something wrong with get from requests.

Comment: @saurabhbaid there seems to be some problem in this case with how the object from the request module is parsed by bs4. With your answer above, I could still only got the first div as output instead of all 5.

Comment: You can download geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases . Remember to add the path to the file in your $PATH environment variable. Also make sure you have firefox installed. You can use the chrome webdriver I believe, but it may have other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I thin the problem is with the parser. I would suggesst to use html5lib parser.
Following code works.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bsa
import requests
url="http://thuvienphapluat.vn"
page_text=requests.get(url).text
soup =Bsa(page_text,"html5lib")
vbpl=soup.select('#VBPLMOI')
for itext in vbpl:
    print itext.prettify(encoding='utf-8')
```

A quick comparison of parser is shown here
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I tried your solution, It's still get 4 div tag of first row of https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gie2.jpg. You can see the compare of vbpl[0] and vbpl[1]: https://ibb.co/dvL3ov. It's not right that I want. The va lue of <div class="number"> is alway 1.

Comment: My bad I havent tested my earlier answer, The actual problem is with the parser. I have updated my answer and tested it as well.